# Trouble with updating account.invoice workflow

Tags: button, workflow, state, invoice, openerp-7

I have updated  my workflow  (add a new object "saved").

Here's the problem :

I must be able to cancel a "Saved" invoice. and since the button "invoice_cancel" already exists (code python ready and works : Indeed, a draft invoice can be cancelled), I just duplicate this button, made it from saved to cancel, and update the XML code to be able to click on cancel button in the "saved" state :

```
 <button name="invoice_cancel" states="draft,proforma2,saved" string="Cancel Invoice"  groups="base.group_no_one"/>
```

With the old states [draft for ex], the canceling can be done. With my new state "saved", I can't cancel the invoice. Any clues?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You might want to have another look at the title you've used as it's not very clear what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably need to change the worflow definition in the xml file in order to add the new transitions. Ex:

```
    <record model="workflow.transition" id="your_new_transition">
        <field name="act_from" ref="saved" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="canceled" />
        <field name="signal">invoice_cancel</field>
    </record>
```